# SQL Server - how to create unique constraint across multiple columns, where one column is VARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to be able create a unique constraint that checks that a string and integer combination is unique.

I have tried code:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT
constraint_Unique_ForeignID_MyString UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
     foreign_id, my_string_col
)
```

But I get error:

> Msg 1919, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'my_string_col' in table
>   'my_string_tbl' is of a type that is
>   invalid for use as a key column in an
>   index.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint.
>   See previous errors.

How can I create the constraint I need?

Comment: Give us the table definition please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How **BIG** of a `VARCHAR` is your column??

Any index can only contain columns up to a maximum of **900 bytes** total. There is no way to get around this, or to increase that number to a higher value.

Comment: It's just domain names in fact, so 100, or 200 chars should be more than enough.

Comment: Actually, just ran the query, max length is 38.

Comment: @BombDefused: the actual length is irrelevant - what is it the column **defined as** in your table?? Is it truly a `VARCHAR(100)`?? Or is it `VARCHAR(2000)` or `VARCHAR(MAX)`, just to be on the safe side....

Comment: Ah.... I see what you mean. The Actual type of the column is nvarchar(max). So I guess I can just change the column type. This project gets worse!

Comment: @BombDefused: make it as big as you need it - but no bigger! If it's domain names as you say - use `NVARCHAR(255)` or something. You don't need 2 GB (2 billion) characters for that - not ever!!

Comment: Agreed (Believe me when I say I didn't design this DB!). Thanks for the help. I'd assumed that the unique restriction was on ALL strings. This makes sense.

Comment: 900 bytes ought to be enough for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

It's either:

- text/ntext/image/varchar(max)/nvarchar(max)/varbinary(max)/xml
- too long > 900 bytes

In this case, you can add a computed column based on a hash of the value and use this for a constraint.

Of course, if you have text/ntext/image then this fails too. So change to one of the newer varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max) types introduced with SQL Server 2005 and hash that